# tcpdump output GET to file

Tags: tcpdump

I wish to run TCP dump on en0 but only receive matches for GET requests to a certain domain, if not just GET requests would be enough. I have tried this but no luck

> Blockquote
>   sudo tcpdump -i en0 -s 0 -A 'tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x47455420’
>   Blockquote

Comment: Have you tried [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)? It will be easier to track/filter protocol level info. You can load captured tcpdump files into wireshark if you can't run gui where the capture is.

Comment: I need to add it to a larger script, once it has created the list of GETs i need to tweak them and replay them with curl/wget and save responses to a folder. I could do it with wireshark, but then again I could also do it line by line with other tools - I am trying to automate somewhat

Answer (score 0):

The bpf filter you're using might actually be correct. It gets the data offset and looks right after it (i.e. the first bytes in the payload of the segment) for "`GET`" which you have there in ASCII.

I tried your filter and it actually worked... for a very small subset of sites. The majority of traffic is now HTTPS not HTTP so finding raw `GET`'s in the wild is rarer.

---

Side note: wireshark which was mentioned in the comments is a good thought. Just in case you're not aware, `tshark` (comes with wireshark) lends itself to automation and can do what you want:

```
tshark -Y 'http.request.method == GET'
```